# Having trouble calling a JPanel from a different class

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface, jpanel

Im trying to create a Hangman game for my java class and im struggling with how to make each class work together. In this case, Im trying to write my phrase in from the selectPhrase method to the mainPanel. Im very new to programming so any help would be very appreciated. 
Thank you

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 * Created by Alex on 4/22/2016.
 */
``public class HangmanGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public HangmanGame() {
        JPanel lettersPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,8,5,5));

        JButton jbtA = new JButton("A");
        JButton jbtB = new JButton("B");
        JButton jbtC = new JButton("C");
        JButton jbtD = new JButton("D");
        JButton jbtE = new JButton("E");
        JButton jbtF = new JButton("F");
        JButton jbtG = new JButton("G");
        JButton jbtH = new JButton("H");
        JButton jbtI = new JButton("I");
        JButton jbtJ = new JButton("J");
        JButton jbtK = new JButton("K");
        JButton jbtL = new JButton("L");
        JButton jbtM = new JButton("M");
        JButton jbtN = new JButton("N");
        JButton jbtO = new JButton("O");
        JButton jbtP = new JButton("P");
        JButton jbtQ = new JButton("Q");
        JButton jbtR = new JButton("R");
        JButton jbtS = new JButton("S");
        JButton jbtT = new JButton("T");
        JButton jbtU = new JButton("U");
        JButton jbtV = new JButton("V");
        JButton jbtW = new JButton("W");
        JButton jbtX = new JButton("X");
        JButton jbtY = new JButton("Y");
        JButton jbtZ = new JButton("Z");

        lettersPanel.add(jbtA);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtB);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtC);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtD);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtE);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtF);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtG);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtH);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtI);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtJ);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtK);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtL);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtM);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtN);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtO);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtP);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtQ);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtR);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtS);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtT);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtU);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtV);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtW);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtX);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtY);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtZ);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,5,5));

        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        mainPanel.add(lettersPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        //mainPanel.add()



        add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new HangmanGame();
        frame.add(new HangmanGraphics());
        frame.setTitle("Hangman");
        frame.setSize(1020, 800);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);


    }
     static String selectPhrase()
    {
        String currentGuess = "*";
        int[] previousValues = new int[5];
        int totalRounds = 0;
        //set isValid equal to false and creates a random number between 1 and 6
        //(between 1 and 6 because previousValues is used to store the old numbers,
        //and if between 0 and 5 were used, 0 would trip every time because an uninitialized
        //array has 0's (null) in every position)
        boolean isValid = false;
        int index = (int)(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

        //enters loop because isValid is false, so !isValid is true
        while(!isValid)
        {
            //sets isValid equal to true, so if it never gets changed during the loop, it will exit next time around
            isValid = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < totalRounds; i++)
            {
                //if the randomly generated value is one of the previous ones, make isValid false
                if(index == previousValues[i])
                {
                    isValid = false;
                }
            }

            //if isValid is false, create a new random number between 1 and 6
            if(!isValid)
            {
                index = (int)(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
            }
        }

        //once a value that's never been used before is created, save it in previousValues
        //so that it is not used again
        previousValues[totalRounds] = index;
        totalRounds++;

        //return phrase at the index of the random number
        String[] phrase = {"NULL", "Go Team", "Hello World" , "Java Rocks", "Bread Bowl" , "Soup"};
        return phrase[index];


        for( int i=0; i<phrase.length; i++) {
            currentGuess = currentGuess.concat("?");
        }
        .setText( currentGuess );

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}

class HangmanGraphics extends JPanel {

    JPanel graphicsPanel = new JPanel();

    int incorrectGuesses =0;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        BasicStroke aStroke = new BasicStroke(15.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
        g2D.setStroke(aStroke);
        g2D.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        switch (incorrectGuesses) {
            case 10:
                g2D.drawLine(200, 200, 150, 250); // Left leg
            case 9:
                g2D.drawLine(200, 200, 250, 250); // Right leg
            case 8:
                g2D.drawLine(150, 150, 200, 175); // Left arm
            case 7:
                g2D.drawLine(250, 150, 200, 175); // Right arm
            case 6:
                g2D.drawLine(200, 200, 200, 150); // Torso
            case 5:
                g2D.drawOval(175, 100, 50, 50); // Head
            case 4:
                g2D.drawLine(200, 100, 200, 50);// Noose
            case 3:
                g2D.drawLine(200, 50, 100, 50);//Plank
            case 2:
                g2D.drawLine(100, 300, 100, 50); //Post
            case 1:
                g2D.drawLine(20, 300, 300, 300); //Stage
        }

        repaint();

        graphicsPanel.add(new HangmanGraphics());

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue, which is common to many if not most new developers, is the over use of `static` and a lack of understanding of Object Oriented Programming, and how to use objects. In your case, you are trying to create a main method inside a `JFrame` type object (`HangmanGame`) and then you have a static method you want to call, typically because you are trying to figure out how to call it from the `static main` method. You are better off creating a separate 'driver' class for `HangManGame`, that contains the main method. The `HangManGame` class then creates an instance of a `HangManFrame` (calls `new HangManFrame()`).

The 2 important points to remember are:

1) In your main method, create an instance of the class that the main is defined in, then call methods on that object. By doing that, you don't need to declare a bunch of static methods and will avoid a lot of pain like you are experiencing now. For example, here is a definition of the `HangManGame` class:

```
package hangman;

public class HangManGame {
    HangManFrame frame;

    public HangManGame(){
        frame = new HangManFrame();
    }

    public void play() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
        String selectedPhrase = selectPhrase();
        System.out.println("Selected phrase: " + selectedPhrase);
    }

    public String selectPhrase() {
        String currentGuess = "*";
        int[] previousValues = new int[5];
        int totalRounds = 0;
        //set isValid equal to false and creates a random number between 1 and 6
        //(between 1 and 6 because previousValues is used to store the old numbers,
        //and if between 0 and 5 were used, 0 would trip every time because an uninitialized
        //array has 0's (null) in every position)
        boolean isValid = false;
        int index = (int)(Math.random() * 5 + 1);

        //enters loop because isValid is false, so !isValid is true
        while(!isValid)
        {
            //sets isValid equal to true, so if it never gets changed during the loop, it will exit next time around
            isValid = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < totalRounds; i++)
            {
                //if the randomly generated value is one of the previous ones, make isValid false
                if(index == previousValues[i])
                {
                    isValid = false;
                }
            }

            //if isValid is false, create a new random number between 1 and 6
            if(!isValid)
            {
                index = (int)(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
            }
        }

        //once a value that's never been used before is created, save it in previousValues
        //so that it is not used again
        previousValues[totalRounds] = index;
        totalRounds++;

        //return phrase at the index of the random number
        String[] phrase = {"NULL", "Go Team", "Hello World" , "Java Rocks", "Bread Bowl" , "Soup"};
        return phrase[index];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HangManGame game = new HangManGame();
        game.play();
    }
}
```

Notice that the only task the main method performs is to create an instance of the `HangManGame` class and call the `play()` method on that object..that's it!

Also notice that the `selectPhrase()` method is not declared static, as it is not necessary.

2) For all your classes, objects that you need access to and need to be able to call methods on should be declared outside of methods as 'class-wide instance variables'. For example, notice how the `HangManFrame` is declared inside the `HangManGame` class, but outside of the methods. Then the frame is created and assigned inside the constructor for `HangManGame

```
 public class HangManGame {
    HangManFrame frame;

    public HangManGame(){
        frame = new HangManFrame();
    }
 ...
}
```

Doing this will allow you to call methods on the frame from within any of the `HangManGame` methods.

I have slightly refactored your `HangManFrame` and `HangManGraphics` class, following similar stategies, included below.

Finally, you should begin to create other methods on the `HangManGame` class, maybe like `nextMove()`, or `updateBoard()` or whatever, that are driven by and called from the `play()` method.

HangManFrame class:

package hangman;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class HangManFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel lettersPanel;

    public HangManFrame() {
        lettersPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 8, 5, 5));

        JButton jbtA = new JButton("A");
        JButton jbtB = new JButton("B");
        JButton jbtC = new JButton("C");
        JButton jbtD = new JButton("D");
        JButton jbtE = new JButton("E");
        JButton jbtF = new JButton("F");
        JButton jbtG = new JButton("G");
        JButton jbtH = new JButton("H");
        JButton jbtI = new JButton("I");
        JButton jbtJ = new JButton("J");
        JButton jbtK = new JButton("K");
        JButton jbtL = new JButton("L");
        JButton jbtM = new JButton("M");
        JButton jbtN = new JButton("N");
        JButton jbtO = new JButton("O");
        JButton jbtP = new JButton("P");
        JButton jbtQ = new JButton("Q");
        JButton jbtR = new JButton("R");
        JButton jbtS = new JButton("S");
        JButton jbtT = new JButton("T");
        JButton jbtU = new JButton("U");
        JButton jbtV = new JButton("V");
        JButton jbtW = new JButton("W");
        JButton jbtX = new JButton("X");
        JButton jbtY = new JButton("Y");
        JButton jbtZ = new JButton("Z");

        lettersPanel.add(jbtA);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtB);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtC);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtD);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtE);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtF);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtG);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtH);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtI);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtJ);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtK);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtL);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtM);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtN);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtO);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtP);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtQ);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtR);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtS);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtT);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtU);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtV);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtW);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtX);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtY);
        lettersPanel.add(jbtZ);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 5, 5));

        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        mainPanel.add(lettersPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(new HangmanGraphics());
        setTitle("Hangman");
        setSize(1020, 800);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Received actionPerformed event: " + e.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```

HangManGraphics class:

package hangman;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class HangmanGraphics extends JPanel {

```
JPanel graphicsPanel = new JPanel();

int incorrectGuesses =0;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    BasicStroke aStroke = new BasicStroke(15.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
    g2D.setStroke(aStroke);
    g2D.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    switch (incorrectGuesses) {
        case 10:
            g2D.drawLine(200, 200, 150, 250); // Left leg
        case 9:
            g2D.drawLine(200, 200, 250, 250); // Right leg
        case 8:
            g2D.drawLine(150, 150, 200, 175); // Left arm
        case 7:
            g2D.drawLine(250, 150, 200, 175); // Right arm
        case 6:
            g2D.drawLine(200, 200, 200, 150); // Torso
        case 5:
            g2D.drawOval(175, 100, 50, 50); // Head
        case 4:
            g2D.drawLine(200, 100, 200, 50);// Noose
        case 3:
            g2D.drawLine(200, 50, 100, 50);//Plank
        case 2:
            g2D.drawLine(100, 300, 100, 50); //Post
        case 1:
            g2D.drawLine(20, 300, 300, 300); //Stage
    }

    repaint();

    graphicsPanel.add(new HangmanGraphics());

}
```

}